# cannot compile ruby 2.1+ `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb

Tags: ruby

I am not using rvm, this is for deploying to a server, I have tried downloading 2.1.7 and 2.2.3, I run configure, make and when I run ruby I get

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: 1. Is it possible you have a number or ruby installations on the same machine (so you install a gem and it installs for one version and than you try to require it from a different Ruby version)? 2. Did you reinstall the gem after installing Ruby (try uninstalling and reinstalling)?

Comment: Definitely looks like a ruby install issue. Uninstall everything. Install just one version (I recommend using rbenv to manage it, totally worth the extra step). Install the gems properly and retry.